# Apenas um campo como True por id de outra tabela

Tags: python, django, imagem, back-end, model

Possuo uma tabela contendo produtos e outra contendo as imagens relacionadas. Consegui fazer com que apenas um item ficasse com o campo "padrao" como True, mas isso está aplicando na tabela como um todo. O que eu gostaria é que apenas uma imagem ficasse como padrão, porém por produto. Essa padrão vai ser utilizada como thumbnail. O método save esta impedindo que tenha mais de um campo 'padrao' como true, pra evitar de pegar 2 imagens no thumbnail. O que eu estou tentando fazer seria uma espécie de filtro onde esse lance de apenas um true seja aplicado por produto, e não todos os produtos da tabela.

**Exemplo de como estou tentando fazer:**

```
Produto_1.Imagem1.padrao = True
Produto_1.Imagem2.padrao = False
Produto_1.Imagem3.padrao = False

Produto_2.Imagem1.padrao = False
Produto_2.Imagem2.padrao = True
Produto_2.Imagem3.padrao = False
```

**Exemplo de como está:**

```
Produto_1.Imagem1.padrao = True
Produto_1.Imagem2.padrao = False
Produto_1.Imagem3.padrao = False
Produto_2.Imagem1.padrao = False
Produto_2.Imagem2.padrao = False
Produto_2.Imagem3.padrao = False
```

**Produtos.models.py (resumido):**

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class ProdutoImagem(models.Model):
    produto = models.ForeignKey(Produto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    padrao = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='produto/produto', max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    def save(self):

        #  SÓ UMA IMAGEM COMO PADRÃO
        if self.padrao:
            produto_imagens = ProdutoImagem.objects.filter(padrao=True)
            for produto_imagem in produto_imagens:
                produto_imagem.padrao = False
                produto_imagem.save()
        super().save()
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo pegar a lógica da sua condição no método `save`; se a imagem a ser salva estiver com o atributo `self.padrao == True` ele vai transformar o valor de ***todas* as outras** para `False`? Se for o caso, o problema com isso é a falta de referência à chave estrangeira `produto` ao fazer o filtro em `produto_imagens = ProdutoImagem.objects.filter(padrao=True)` — no caso você precisaria especificar também o objeto de `produto` (p.ex. `produto=self.produto`) que está relacionado para conseguir obter somente as imagens associadas àquele produto.

Comment: O método save esta impedindo que tenha mais de um campo 'padrao' como true, pra evitar de pegar 2 imagens no thumbnail. Mas falta justamente o que falou, o filter para separar um true apenas por produto. Mas já perdi a noite toda tentando fazer isso. kkkk  
"ele vai transformar o valor de todas as outras para False" - Não deveria, ele deveria ter um padrao==true por produto.id.

Answer (score -2):

RESOLVIDO
Por fim tentei a coisa mais simples e só adicionei mais um campo para filtrar no método save. Obrigado Rfroes87 pela luz.

```
class ProdutoImagem(Base):
    produto = models.ForeignKey(Produto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    padrao = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='produto/produto', max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)    

    def save(self):
        if self.padrao:
            produto_imagens = ProdutoImagem.objects.filter(padrao=True, produto=self.produto.pk)
            for produto_imagem in produto_imagens:
                produto_imagem.padrao = False
                produto_imagem.save()
        super().save()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).